# How to install Flash player on Opera?

Tags: thirdpartyapps, video-player

I can't watch any videos on southpark.cc.com or facebook, I tried to install flash player like in opera's tutorial but i don't have a folder called plugins in opera's main folder. I installed it from commands and so on and when I wanted to go on "opera://plugins" there is no plugin, I have only the reader plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/10/pepper-flash-chromium-opera-ubuntu/ 
I am sorry that i posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe's Flash will be installed if you install the ubuntu-restricted-extras.
You will not see any Flash plugin installed on Opera's plugin section.  I actually wanted to disable flash plugin.. but found that out. I use opera as well.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: When I do this the red backgrounded screen which titled 'Configuring ttt-fmscorefonct-installer' screen starts and Process bar on the bottom freezes.